# Unity 5 crashes under Mac OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, graphic, osx-yosemite

Did someone have this problem for Mac OSX Yosemite. Project size is over 250Mb after build.

Computer params: MacBook 13 i7 CPU, 16Gb RAM, 1,5GB GPU

EDIT: [The full crash log from Mac OSX](http://pastebin.com/U6P40gmW)

Screenshot of some crash log:

[image]

[The full crash log from Mac OSX](http://pastebin.com/U6P40gmW)

Comment: Can you please the crash log as a text instead? Unfortunately, it's very hard to scroll text inside a screenshot.

Comment: It says that your graphics hardware encountered an error. Do you get similar crashes in other 3d-heavy software? Have you tried checking if your graphics adapter is ok?

Comment: Sure :) to be honest I didn't find a way to post the log as a text, that's why I did it like that.

Comment: Does this error appear regularly or only one time? What have changed in your project when this error started appearing?

Comment: It appears when I try to run the game. It happens after few seconds , sometimes from the beginning. The same issue exists on other Mac Book which is installed from different image of Yosemite. The same project runs on Win8 without any problem.

Comment: Do you get this error only when you run the editor or only the build?

Comment: I get the error both for the build and when I try to run it in Unity.

Comment: Did you build the app with `x86`, `x86_64`, or `Universal` architecture? Have you tried changing it?

Comment: What are your player options for the platform: rendering path, color space, direct3d 11, batching, api compatibility levels, optimization settings? Have you tried changing it?

Comment: Architecture for the build was x86_64, but I think it doesn't make any difference running the game package under the unity. I have tried to enable settings which are you mentioned. Those are: direct3d 11, batching, optimisation settings and e.t.c.

Comment: This looks like a genuine Unity bug, I would report it.

Comment: I just tried to build the same under Win8 for Mac os platform and actually it has been crashed as well :)

Comment: So, what did you change since the last stable commit?