# Unity crash on OS X: UnityGfxDeviceWorker thread crashed

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, osx-elcapitan, sigabrt

When I zoom or rotate the camera my Unity app tends to crash. I include a short version of the crash report and a link to a complete version. More details on my research follow.

Thank you for your support.

```
Process:               Unity [1174]
Path:                  /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity
Identifier:            com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x
Version:               Unity version 5.3.4f1 (5.3.4f1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Unity [1174]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2016-04-11 15:54:02.621 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.2 (15C50)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        07764B5C-AB89-7381-3C4F-EA3FF9B00068

Sleep/Wake UUID:       5EE47DBD-49A9-439C-9848-9B88CA856A8C

Time Awake Since Boot: 16000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        38  UnityGfxDeviceWorker

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

Another section, that seems relevant:

```
Thread 38 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x000070000a32cc78  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000001d71f  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x000070000a32cca0  rsp: 0x000070000a32cc78
   r8: 0x0000000000000040   r9: 0x00007fff7c7551e0  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000109dde751  r13: 0x00007fff7c755bd0  r14: 0x000070000a32f000  r15: 0x00000000000004ae
  rip: 0x00007fff96062002  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff7bf18118

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

You can find the entire report here: http://pastebin.com/D0L7CX9W

My research so far on the topic are searches on stackoverflow with the tags associated with the post. After reading some I discarded the results for iOS or other applications as non-helpful.

The closest match I found was the unanswered question here: [Unity 5 crashes under Mac OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145042/unity-5-crashes-under-mac-osx-yosemite), although with some possily significant differences. I'm using El-Capitan, a newer version of unity (5.3.4f1 vs 5.0.0f4) and my crash report is from within Unity and not from a Unity built application. It is however the same thread which has crashed "UnityGfxDeviceWorker", so perhaps they have the same solution.

Other searches of mine have not been successful in finding a similar problem as in this case of Unity crashing, other than when building, starting up or similar.

Again, thank you for taking the time of reading this and I am grateful for you help.

Comment: I would recommend making sure everything is fully up to date, including Unity and OSX. Test this on an older version of Unity to verify.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Having the same issue now...

Comment: no, sorry, no idea

Comment: Care to share the entries of `/Users/[your user name]/Library/Logs/Unity/Player.log` if available?

Comment: Same problem here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this crash on iOS. I fixed this by only using OpenGL ES2.0 in Unity. You could try using only using OpenGL and turning off Metal.
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1283609/gfx-device-intialization-failed-and-crash-on-ios-s.html

Comment: it's been a while since I saw this. Don't think I can reproduce now. I would like to mark your answer as correct, but need some more evidence for it being correct

Comment: @MatthiasMichaelEngh I've added a link.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by unchecking Metal API Validation flag in Edit Scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics in Xcode. Using Unity 2020.1.9f1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that worked for me.  In my build settings, I went into **Other Settings>Mac App Store Options** and changed the **Bundle Identifier** to something other than the default *com.Company.ProductName*.  I'm guessing I had some kinda name collision or something.

Anyway, I made it *com.Company.ProductName2* and it worked.  This is a workaround, so not sure what is causing the problem - my OSX-fu is weak.